# .htaccess for 301 rewrite for www/non www canonical, with exceptions for subfolder (another domain)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, web

I have a domain and host it on godaddy.com. I have firstsite.com which is in the root of the hosting account. I have an .htaccess file for this site which works fine, and does a simple redirect of all `firstsite.com` traffic to `www.firstsite.com`. It is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.firstsite\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.firstsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I have added a new domain to my hosting account, which is contained within a subfolder on the site: `/secondsite`

Without the .htaccess file, when I go to `secondsite.com` it displays as `secondsite.com`. However, with the .htaccess file, it displays as `www.firstsite.com/secondsite`.

I would like to have the www/non www canonical .htaccess work for the first site, but still have the second site displaying correctly, also with www/non www canonical resolved.

I have searched everywhere for this specific issue, but have not found how to code the .htaccess file. Can someone give me a quick example of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In your case (multiple domains pointing to the same folder) you need to be more specific when specifying domain name. Instead of negate use match:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^firstsite\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.firstsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect requests to `http://firstsite.com/bla-bla` to `http://www.firstsite.com/bla-bla` but will not touch `secondsite.com` as well as will not touch `http://anything.firstsite.com/bla-bla`.

Comment: Thanks for that! For the secondsite.com, if I want to resolve the canonical for that as well, would I be best off to then put another .htaccess file within the /secondsite folder? Or could another rule be added to the .htaccess of the root folder?

Comment: I added the same file to the /secondsite folder (with "secondsite" specified instead of "firstsite" of course) and everything now works great, and the canonical resolves for both sites. Thanks again!